# Yoasts plugin sitemap not detecting correct category URL format

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

My client wants the following URL:

```
https://example.com/category-name
```

So for that, I added `.` in the Category base under Settings > Permalinks and now my Category URL looks like how the client wants it: `https://example.com/category-name/`

However, the category sitemap generated by Yoasts shows like this:

```
https://example.com/./category-name/
```

How can I resolve this? Google isn't crawling the above category URLs and I'm assuming this is the reason for it.

I'm getting "Sitemaps: No referring sitemaps detected" on Google Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `.` may be a bad idea.

This issue may be causing Google to not crawl your category URLs, which can result in the "Sitemaps: No referring sitemaps detected" message you're seeing in Google Search Console.

It's important to note that any changes to your permalink structure can impact your website's SEO, so make sure to test everything thoroughly and set up proper redirects if necessary.